# Join when exact match other other wise join with default value

Tags: sql, oracle, join

```
I have two table a and b
```

table a

```
   ID 
    a
    b
    c
```

table b

```
   ID           Value
   a             1   
   b             2
   default       0
```

So I want to join two tables on ID when exactly matching, otherwise use default value
The desired results

```
   ID           Value
   a             1   
   b             2
   c             0
```

Comment: Which DBMS you are using? tag you question with that.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for that purpose like

```
select t1.ID, COALESCE(t2.Value, 0) as Value
from tablea t1 
left join tableb t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

Comment: But the default value could be any value that I don't know, so I can't use coalesce

Comment: @JiaoWang, read about `JOINS` in SQL. You can't use that default value. if you do a inner join you lost that record all together else perform outer join like in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.ID, b.Value
FROM a
INNER JOIN b
ON a.ID = b.ID
UNION ALL
SELECT a.ID, b.Value
FROM a
CROSS JOIN b
WHERE
    a.id <> b.id
```

This will provide you with all matching IDs, then the UNION of the CROSS JOIN query should provide the default value for non-matching IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   SELECT t1.ID, 
          COALESCE(t2.Value, (SELECT Value FROM tableb t3 WHERE ID ='default')) AS Value
     FROM tablea t1 
LEFT JOIN tableb t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID;
```